# Right-to-Left text-direction in PySimpleGUI

Tags: json, python, python-3.7, right-to-left, pysimplegui

Does `PySimpleGUI` python library support RTL alignment?

I want to align Arabic text from right-to-left:

[image]

Code:

```
sg.Text("احب الطعام", font='12', size=(15, 1), background_color='#81a5b3')
```

Comment: Option `justification='right'` ?

Comment: @JAsonYang nope, this just align the text to the right.

Comment: Can you show me how it will look like for "RTL" ?

Comment: @JasonYang it gives the same output as for `right`

Comment: Sorry, don't understand arabic language, so don't know the right way of so-called "RTL". Maybe I know the way to go, but don't know the target to go.

Comment: Does it mean "reversed"?   word = drow?  Is that an oversimplification that describes what you mean?  I think Hebrew is similar.

Answer (score 0):

**just add to your sg.text() element.

> justification="right"**

Comment: Please have a look at the comment by @JasonYang

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with Visual Studio itself rather than PySimpleGUI.
You can make typing in Right-To-Left languages (like Arabic, Persian, Hebrew, etc) work by doing the following:

**Solution**

1. In Visual Studio Code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type `>settings` in search bar and open `Open User Settings (JSON)` *
3. Add the line `"editor.renderControlCharacters": false` and save the settings.json file.

*You can set settings either to apply for everything the current Windows `User` opens, `Default` for the application so for all users' everything, or only per specific `Workspace`.

Now, after a recent VS update only this *should* be enough for it to work: it will recognize when you are typing in a RTL language. If for some reason it does not work, also do the following:

**Potential/additional workaround**

- Manually add the unicode RTF character `U+202B` (or copy-paste from somewhere like [here](https://symbl.cc/en/202B/)) at the start of the entry you want to type.

I've tested it just now and it does work fine, but doesn't seem to love copy/pasted text instead of typed which could be annoying for long entries if it decides not to work with you for some reason.

**Keyboard toggle**

You can bind a key to toggle between RTL and LTR to make life easier in case you go back and forth a lot.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type in search bar and open `Open Keyboard shortcuts`  (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
3. Add `editor.action.toggleRenderControlCharacter` to the search bar and set whatever keybind you want.

What this does is effectively add / remove the .json edit that is the solution (i.e. enable/disable RTL).

Comment: This enables PySimpleGUI input to be right to left?  What if not using Visual Studio?

Comment: It enables right to left on Visual Studio Code itself, it was a known issue only solved in recent years (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/136347). Even in Visual Studio 2022 the problem does not get replicated, I had to install VSCode to get it. You can test it by adding any RTL language (eg Arabic) to your OS keyboard and use the on-screen keyboard to type a few characters in VSC vs other IDEs (or even a web browser). The issue was with Pylance (comes bundled with Python in VSC). For other IDEs, they should work without any fix OR with the unicode character U+202B entered/copy pasted.

Comment: Sorry, and to clarify: for user input via e.g. a Python app with PySimpleGUI user text input, no fix is needed. That's taken care of natively by the OS. Here's a pic of me testing it in Visual Studio 2022 on a demo GUI: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/313716430321352704/1133827743755292722/image.png

Comment: :D missed edit timeframe. Follows: for user input via eg a Python app with PySimpleGUI user text input, no fix *should* (dunno if would) be needed because that's taken care of natively by the OS when using a RTL keyboard language. Test on demo GUI (VSS2022 irrelevant, no changes done at all other than switch kb language): https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/313716430321352704/1133827743755292722/image.png 
I entered the middle row letter characters one by one starting from Enter to test it, and it seems to my untrained eye that it worked fine. Copy-paste behavior can still be weird though.

Comment: Ah... OK, I'll remove my answer... it doesn't help anyone and only confuses.  Thanks for the clarification.